# Display postdate Spout Forms entries

Tags: plugin-sproutforms, postdate

I'm trying to display the postDate of Sprout Forms entries. The docs state that you can use standard Craft CMS tags. I tried:

```
{% for formEntry in craft.sproutForms.entries.formHandle('contact').order(asc) %}
   {{ formEntry.postDate|date('d F Y') }}
{% endfor %}
```

And all kind of variations but the system states no method or closure with the name "postDate". All other fields output fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer in the database. Apparently Sprout Forms uses the date field named "dateCreated". Also getting it in order by date (newest first) needs 'dateCreated desc'

```
{% for formEntry in craft.sproutForms.entries.formHandle('contact').order('dateCreated desc') %}
   {{ formEntry.dateCreated|date('d F Y') }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Using `dateCreated` is the recommended way.  `postDate` is an attribute specific to the Entry Element Type.